# Ajax remove item from WooCommerce cart issue in a custom theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Link on my site with issue [ISSUE](https://genreeds.ru/cart/)

So friends. Hi all.
I almost completely fixed all the bugs and perfected the Botig theme ([Link theme Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/themes/botiga/))
With your help, of course.

There is only 1 bad moment left. The item deletion cross does not work.

[image]

The cross DOES NOT WORK - when I select "postname" instead of "simple" in the Wookomers settings.
[image]

But, the cross WORKS - when I choose this setting ("simple")
[image]

I can't use the "simple" setting. I prefer to use the "postname" setting.

What else I noticed. When setting "postname" - the cross in the MINI-BASKET works!!
[image]

What can I do? How to fix this problem? Maybe there is some code, snippet or something?
I will never figure it out myself, little knowledge ...

Any help! Please.

Below I will throw off 2 codes. 1st: a cross for a mini basket
2nd: a cross for a shopping cart (cart page) that doesn't work.

Mini-cart, working cross code
[image]

Page-cart, dont working cross code (when %postname% setting woocommerce)
[image]

I think this class should be changed to "class=remove remove_from_cart_button"
[image]

P. S. For now, I've selected the "simple" setting. And of course the cross works. On the shopping cart page.

But is there a way to make everything work when you select "postname"??
Change the class or some other snippet to make, a crutch, and so on...

Working links - [image]

Dont working - [image]

Comment: I returned "simple" links instead of "postname".

There were 13 errors, but the cross began to work

But it doesn't suit me.

Comment: Made "simple". Made a "postname".

Number of errors 13. Does not change. That's not the problem. 100%.

Why when you choose "simple" - the cross works.

And when "postname" does not work?

The number of errors on the page does NOT change

Comment: Let me now make "simple" and you will test.

Now everything works. The cross works.

I think I need to write "class=remove remove_from_cart_button" in "class=remove"

This can be done?

Comment: There are 91 errors on the Google translator website :D
And everything works

Comment: I have now created an "clear cart" button.
And button does not work regardless of the settings.

Though - "postname". Though - "simple".

does not work.

Hmm .... Problem

P.S. Returned the "postname" setting again

Need to deal with this JQuery file?

Comment: Loic. Hello!

I found these lines on my hosting. I have everything exactly the same in the files ... Well, that is, these lines 487-501. They are the same and they are.
It's strange that it doesn't work :(((

Comment: Loic. I added 2 more pictures on my problem. Where Ajax works. And where it doesn't work.

Maybe this way you can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site is perfect. And the problem was not in the cache, not in the plugin, not in the theme.
No.

The problem was hosting. Nginx.

Everyone can have such a problem (and IT WILL BE!!) if you deploy a site on nginx.

Get to the point.

We go into the nginx config and change the line to the following -

```
 location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }
```

After that, "permalinks" like - shopping cart, home, my contacts - will work perfectly!
Scripts will work perfectly.

P.S. thanks (no) for helping.
I know why everyone didn't give a shit, because the problem is unrealistically complex and not typical. Here stupid advice - reinstall Windows, delete caches, cookies, and so on will not help.
There are no errors either, the scripts work perfectly.

I would probably do the same :)

P. P. S. I also modified this script.
When you delete a product (on a cross) - it is deleted on the cart page.
But the mini cart icon is NOT updated. And shows as if there are goods.

To fix this, you need to modify the jQuery.

```
/usr/share/nginx/***************/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php
```

Next, search and change to: `<a href="%s" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="% s">&times;</a>',`

And add this one more: `esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),`

We change the button class and add an attribute.

Result: Both the mini cart and the cart page are updated.

I am over the mind.

Comment: By the way. "Elementor" - is also repaired by the same method.