# Refinement of the javascript jQuery mini-basket update script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Website with a [ISSUE](https://genreeds.ru/cart/)

I have a script working. When I click "+ or -" in the basket - the cost changes and the quantity of goods too. Without page refresh.

```js
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );

function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', 'input.qty', function(){
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").removeAttr("disabled").trigger("click");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Question.

Is it possible to modify this script in such a way that the quantity of goods in the mini-basket also changes?

Because when adding and reducing the quantity of goods - the mini basket does not react ...
Quantity does not change

```
jQuery('span.count-number').text(jQuery('#quantity_64aaf3adc036a').val());
```

do not working

[image]

Comment: You could use `jQuery("[name='update_cart']").html("<span>5 units</span>")` or `jQuery("[name='update_cart']").text("5 units")`. If you want to send an AJAX request, use jQuery.ajax() or jQuery.getJSON().

Comment: I understand it.
And I've tried it in different ways. What code will be in the end - that is the question.

The script works great. Updates the cost and quantity of the item on the cart page. But the script should also update the quantity in the mini-cart.
And mini-cart doesn't update.
The script needs to be improved.

How? This is a question for you and the community :)

Comment: You have many options. I don't know your HTML content so I can`t decide for you. Maybe jQuery().text("value") is enough for you.

Comment: Wouldn't the combination "CTRL+SHIFT+C" give you comprehensive information?

All sites on woocommerce are identical to each other.

I gave a link to the site :D

Or is something else needed?

Comment: No, you should give us a MRE. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have already provided the code. Anyone who is engaged in "woocommerce" will be able to prompt immediately. Straightaway.

My code works great. It only needs to be finalized so that there is a bunch with a mini basket. And that's it.

It is necessary that not only the cart page is updated, but also the number of items in the mini cart.

The mini-cart Icon.

If I send you the HTML code, it will be a 100 page book.

And it will be inconvenient.

And if follow the link and look - business for 30 seconds. That's all

Comment: Simple, select that mini-cart icon and insert a new text. Something like `jQuery("market-icon .indicator").text("5")`.

Comment: Friend. I have uploaded a screenshot. Brief

Comment: Have a look, please. Right now the number 5 is displayed.
But I didn't really need it.

Comment: how to make it interactive?

Comment: Or how do I copy the value from "input"?

Comment: jQuery('span.count-number').text(jQuery('#quantity_64aaf3adc036a').val()); 

Do not working